# AnyChart: Line Marker goes behind the bar

Tags: anychart

I just started to learn AnyChart and I just have completed my first chart by using it. However, I don't know why the line marker goes behind the bars. I checked the
Is there any possibility to use something like a zindex? I would appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot

[Screenshot of my bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f42W.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a line marker, you can set its appearance by using the `stroke()` method, like this:

```
var lineMarker = chart.lineMarker();
  lineMarker.value(9000);
  lineMarker.stroke({
    thickness: 3,
    color: '#7E57C2',
    dash: "2 4",
  });
```

In your case, if you want to change its z-index just call the `zIndex()` method on the `lineMarker` and on the series variable:

```
var series = chart.bar(data);
  series.zIndex(1);

lineMarker.zIndex(2);
```

The bigger the index, the higher the element position is.

If you would like to learn more about marker's appearance, please check [the documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Line_Markers).